# i have two components{addressone},{addresstwo} and want to add and delete {addresstwo} on button click inside {addressone} component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, events

**address two component**

```
 `<AddressTwo/>`
```

**i had applied toggle logic but i am trying to add and delete component**

```
  <Button
    onClick={()=>setIsToggled(!isToggled)}>+</Button>

    {isToggled && <AddressTwo/>}
```

*add when this is clicked*

```
   `<Button >+</Button>`
```

*remove component when this button is clicked*

```
  ` <Button>-</Button>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your way to do,

think that the address is one component that receives 1 object

```js
{ id: Number, street: String, number: String, postCode: String }
```

and the number of addresses is an array of object

```js
[ {...}, {...}]
```

in react it's maybe easier to manage this way

```js
const [addresses, setAdresses] = useState([])

const addOne = () => setAddresses([...addresses, { id: null, street: "", number: "", postCode: "" }]

{...}

return(
  <>
    <h1>hello from profile</h1>
    <button onclick={()=>addOne()}/>+</button>
    {addresses.map((address, i)=>(
       <AddressComponent address={address} />
    )}
  </>
)
```

the code is not perfect but you got the IDEA

then from there, you can play with the array as you want... (pop, push, limit, find, etc...)

courage...